# Play 2.2.0 - How to create a war file

Tags: java, tomcat, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using play 2.2.0 for my application so inorder to host the application i need to create a war file so i can host in my Tomcat7 server. So is there any method to

1. Clean and Build as we have options in netbeans with console.
2. Create war file so i can host.
3. The method to create a war file as in normal jsp hosting i paste all my class files in WEB_INF folder but here how can i do please tell the procedure. I just gave few try this i have mentioned below i know i am wrong please show me the right way.

   F:\Play_workspace\ThemePractice>play war
   [info] Loading project definition from F:\Play_workspace\ThemePractice\project
   [info] Set current project to ThemePractice (in build file:/F:/Play_workspace/Th
   emePractice/)
   [error] Not a valid command: war (similar: start)
   [error] Not a valid project ID: war
   [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
   [error] Not a valid key: war (similar: watch, run, apiUrl)
   [error] war
   [error]    ^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [plugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/) for creating a war file, however Play 2.2.x is currently not supported.

Although a [branch](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/tree/feature-#188-be-compatible-with-Play-2.2) exists on Github for this feature, it looks like it is [still](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/issues/188) being [worked](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/pull/191) on. You'd have to contact the maintainers for a time line.

**Update:** It is now possible to create a war file with Play 2.2.x, see Paul D. Eden's comment.

Comment: As of today there is a version that may work for 2.2.x.  v1.2-beta4 at https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/releases

Answer (score 1):

Play 2.1.4 onwards, support for packaging into a war file has been withdrawn. There is a workaround for the same which can help you in generating war file. You fool the compiler and let it think that we are using earlier version of Play. For details refer to the following link :-

[Create War from Play 2.2.1 application](http://play2war.blogspot.in/)

It is working till day for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.2-beta4")` to your `plugins.sbt`

Add the following to your build.sbt

```
import com.github.play2war.plugin._

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.play2war" % "play2-war_2.9.1" % "0.8.2"
)


Play2WarPlugin.play2WarSettings

Play2WarKeys.servletVersion := "2.5"
```

Now you can freely use the "play war" command.